# How do I pull a image by gridview position

Tags: android, gridview

Everything is working normally just picture is not shown

BaseAdapter:

```
public Bitmap getItem(int position) {
    return bitmaps.get(position);
}
```

Activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SpcifiesImage.class);
                    // passing array index
                    i.putExtra("id", position);`enter code here`
                    startActivity(i);
```

this is the activity that i want that the image There will :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SpcifiesImage.class);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    CustomGrid imageAdapter = new CustomGrid(mContext);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(imageAdapter.bitmaps.get(position));


    // passing array index
    intent.putExtra("mas", massage);

    startActivity(intent);
```

CustomGrid:

```
         Context mContext;
private Bitmap btimaprecieve;
List<ParseObject> ParseObjects;
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps;
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
int size;


public CustomGrid(Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps) {
    mContext = c;
    this.bitmaps = bitmaps;

}

public CustomGrid(Context mContext) {
}


//---returns the number of images---
public int getCount() {
    return bitmaps.size();
}

//---returns the ID of an item---
public Bitmap getItem(int position) {
    return bitmaps.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(mContext);

        // get layout from mobile.xml
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile, null);

        // set value into textview
       // TextView textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
      //  textView.setText(mobileValues[position]);

        // set image based on selected text
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
       // imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
       // imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(position));


    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }
    return gridView;
```

logcat:

Process: com.example.tepper.myapplication, PID: 16637
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

Comment: Can you show the code populating adapter images please?

Comment: I'm guessing that @MightySeal was referring to the `CustomGrid` code.

The position you are referring to, is it a position of an image on a GridView that the user selected? Or do you get the position in an another way? I guess I didn't fully understand your question/problem.

Comment: is it a position of an image on a GridView that the user selected... look The user clicks on an item in the gridview and the picture he clicked I want to send another activity

Comment: i have the images in the gridview but i cant take the image that the user Press

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from the code you posted, you have a problem with this part:

On CustomGrid:

```
public CustomGrid(Context mContext) {
}
```

The constructor is empty which means that when you do this:

```
CustomGrid imageAdapter = new CustomGrid(mContext); 

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
imageView.setImageBitmap(imageAdapter.bitmaps.get(position));
```

The `bitmaps` array will not be initialized.
You have to either make the Bitmap array static or store it in a place that can be accessed from another activity, just for the purpose of testing do this:

- Change the following line on CustomGrid:

  `ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps;` to `public static ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps;`
- Then on the next activity access it like this:

  `imageView.setImageBitmap(CustomGrid.bitmaps.get(position));`

Comment: and this code is not code because it makes no sense to run the department again

Comment: I'm sorry then, I still don't know what you are asking.. try posting your `CustomGrid` class code and your XML layout code, maybe that will clarify your issue

Comment: Your edit was rejected by the reviewers. You have to edit your question, not my answer :)

Comment: i changed it to imageView.setImageBitmap(CustomGrid.bitmaps.get(position));  but it has error in "position"

Comment: you have to help me I can not for two days

Comment: you have to leave the previous code in `Intent i = getIntent();` and `int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");`

Comment: what is "Attraction Images"?

Comment: ok it is course here : int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");               LogCat: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: this what i have in first activity: startActivity(new Intent (getApplicationContext(),SpcifiesImage.class).putExtra("id",bitmaps.get(position)));

Comment: but i get the image in low quality

Comment: what do you mean by low quality?
What is the resolution of the original images? And what is the size of the imageview you are using?

Comment: i dont know..                                                                            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:src="@drawable/background_pik" >
    </ImageView>

Comment: i mean to Image quality.. bit pixels